# NSFileManager URL vs Path

Tags: ios, url, nsfilemanager

Why is that URL methods like `moveItemAtURL:toURL:error:` of `NSFileManager` class are recommended over Path methods like `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` ?

Answer (score 5):

When NSURL objects are created it's also checked that the path is valid, otherwise the object is not created.

The path ones are created even if it's an invalid path. There are no checks made at all.