# 'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, path

I'm getting the error

```
'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use 'stringByAppendingPathComponent' on NSString instead.
```

when I try to do

```
let documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let databasePath = documentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")
```

This apparently worked for people before, but it doesn't work for me now in Xcode 7 beta 5.

[This thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13580) on the Apple Developer Forums had the suggestion to use an extension or do a direct cast to `NSString`. But if I do convert it to an `NSString`

```
let databasePath = documentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.sqlite" as NSString)
```

then I get the error

```
'NSString' is not implicitly convertible to 'String'...
```

and it gives me the option to "fix-it" by inserting `as String`, which brings us back to the original error.

This also happens for `stringByAppendingPathExtension`.

What do I do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can create a URL rather rather than a String path.

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
let fileURL = documentsURL?.appendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")
```

If you absolutely need the path, then you can get it like this:

```
guard let path = fileURL?.path else {
    return
}

print(path) // path will exist at this point
```

There was some discussion in the [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13580) you mentioned that Apple may be purposely guiding people toward using URLs rather than String paths.

**See also:**

- [What's the difference between path and URL in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546033/whats-the-difference-between-path-and-url-in-ios)
- [NSFileManager URL vs Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023679/nsfilemanager-url-vs-path)
- [Swift 2.0: Why Guard is Better than If](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-guard-better-than-if/)

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
let dbPath = (documentsFolder as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("db.sqlite")
```

Comment: Although this is working it would be great to see this method in Swifts String instead of NSString...